# UserControl inside UserControl is not reflecting data from ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, user-controls

In MainWindow, I am setting its contant to be a UserControl -

```
<Grid>
    <local:MainControl></local:MainControl>
</Grid>
```

In MainControl, I am using other UserControls -

```
    <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1">
            <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0"></GradientStop>
            <GradientStop Color="LightBlue" Offset="1"></GradientStop>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Grid.Background>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="300"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
        <ui:TestHeader Height="20" Padding="20" Margin="2" Background="Gray"></ui:TestHeader>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Here TestHeader is a simple UserControl -

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <model:TestViewModel></model:TestViewModel>
</UserControl.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label Grid.Row="0" Content="{Binding Path=Test}"/>
</Grid>
```

Now I am able to see the data comming from ViewModel, when I use TestHeader directly in MainWindow, However when I use the same TestHeader in MainControl, its not getting data from ViewModel. How can I tackle this. I think, I missed something, but don't know what.

Please suggest the solution. Thanks in Advance.

**Update**

I found this -

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <ui:TestHeader Height="20" Padding="20" Margin="2" Background="Gray"></ui:TestHeader>
    </Grid>
    <ui:TestHeader Grid.Row="0" Background="Gray" Height="20"></ui:TestHeader>
```

here, whole contant is in Grid of MainWindow. The outer TestHeader is populating the data, however, the TestHeader inside the Grid is not.

**Update**

I got my silliest mistake ever -

See the padding and height, both are 20. There is no space for contant.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your `DataContext` (to the ViewModel) at the parent user control and then use the Properties of the ViewModel to bind it to the properties of your controls.